# Pygsheets: How to highlight cells in a specific column based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, pygsheets

I have a pandas data frame with three columns, and I want to highlight the cells in a specific column that meet a certain condition using pygsheets. How can I do that?

```
A                 B          C 
some_text         65      some_text


def color_my_cell(var):
    for i in wks.range('B3:B30'):
        if var < 70:
           wks.cell( NOT SURE what to do here).color = (1.0,0,1.0,1.0)

df['B'] = df['B'].apply(color_my_cell)
```

So, for any cells in  B < 70, highlight cells blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant apply formats in df directly. you can do this by coloring cells by acessing each cell and setting color. but i think in your case whats more appropriate is conditional formatting. something like shown below. below code might not be exatly what you require
refer to [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting) and [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addconditionalformatrulerequest)

```
request = {"AddConditionalFormatRuleRequest": {
"ranges":[GridRange(worksheet=wks, start='B3', end='B30').to_json()],
"booleanRule": {
"condition":{"type::'NUMBER_GREATER', 'values': 70},
"format":{"backgroundColor":{"color": {"green": 0.8,},}}}},
"index":0}

ssheet.custom_request(request, "*")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that's exactly what I was looking for.